# Facing weird issues on deserialization via JSONAPI-Serializer

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization

If i do like this

```js
var JSONAPIDeserializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Deserializer;

var UserDeserialize = new JSONAPIDeserializer('id');
UserDeserialize.deserialize({ data: [ { type: 'ids', id: '1' }, { type: 'ids', id: '2' } ] })
.then(a => console.log(a))
```

I am able to get desired output of deserialization

> [ { id: '1' }, { id: '2' } ]

But if i create a variable of serialized data and try to serialize the same like this

```js
var JSONAPIDeserializer = require('jsonapi-serializer').Deserializer;

var test = "{ data: [ { type: 'ids', id: '1' }, { type: 'ids', id: '2' } ] }"
var UserDeserialize = new JSONAPIDeserializer('id');
UserDeserialize.deserialize(test)
.then(a => console.log(a))
```

I am getting error like this way:-

```
/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/jsonapi-serializer/lib/deserializer-utils.js:70
    var dest = keyForAttribute(from.attributes || {});
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
    at extractAttributes (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/jsonapi-serializer/lib/deserializer-utils.js:70:36)
    at module.exports.perform (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/jsonapi-serializer/lib/deserializer-utils.js:123:13)
    at resource (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/jsonapi-serializer/lib/deserializer.js:26:10)
    at module.exports.deserialize (/Users/acid/node_js/node_modules/jsonapi-serializer/lib/deserializer.js:39:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/acid/node_js/localhost/velekaam/serial.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:540:3
```

How I can correct this ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace...

```
var test = "{ data: [ { type: 'ids', id: '1' }, { type: 'ids', id: '2' } ] }"
UserDeserialize.deserialize(test)
```

...with:

```
var test = '{"data":[{"type":"ids","id":"1"},{"type":"ids","id":"2"}]}'
UserDeserialize.deserialize(JSON.parse(test))
```

...or, with:

```
var test = { data: [ { type: 'ids', id: '1' }, { type: 'ids', id: '2' } ] }
UserDeserialize.deserialize(test)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. so if i need to parse this thing  `{ "data": [ { "type": '',"id": function(){require('child_process').exec('ls /', function(error,stdout, stderr) { console.log(stdout) });}() } ] } `  how I will enter this ?